# Function to calculate average of multiple lists

Tags: interpolation

I have several lists of experimental data `f[x]` with different intervals `Δx` including some noise.

```
listAll = {
   list1 = Table[{x, Exp[1/x + 1] + RandomReal[]}, {x, 0.1, 3, 0.02}],
   list2 = Table[{x, Exp[1/x - 1] + RandomReal[]}, {x, 0.1, 3, 0.03}]
   };
```

I'd now like to create a function that calculated the average of the values in the lists and their standard deviation.
This is how far I got:

```
interpol[data_] := Interpolation /@ data
average[data_, res_] := Table[
   {x, 
    Mean[Table[interpol[data][[y]][x], {y, Length@data}]],
    StandardDeviation[Table[interpol[data][[y]][x], {y, Length@data}]]},
   {x, Max[data[[;; , 1, 1]]], Min[data[[;; , -1, 1]]], res}];
```

which looks plotted this:

```
ListPlot[{list1, list2, average[listAll, 0.02][[;; , {1, 2}]]}]
```

[image: plot]

I have two questions.

- Is a way to use `# &` to access my list data instead of using the nested `Table`?
- Is it possible to use `BSplineFunction` instead of `Interpolation` to reduce the influence of the noise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filtering first:

```
filetredLists = Transpose /@ ({#1, WienerFilter[#2, 6, .1]} & @@@ Transpose /@ listAll);
ip = Interpolation /@ filetredLists;
average[x_] := Mean@Through[ip[x]]; 
Plot[average[x], {x, .2, 3}, Epilog -> Point /@ listAll, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 40}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you! `Through` is exactly the function I needed and filtering the data before is a great idea. I'll take a look into the different filter option to know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to interpolate the full sets of points, and then average the interpolating functions.

```
intL1 = Interpolation[list1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
intL2 = Interpolation[list2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[{intL1[x], intL2[x], (intL1[x] + intL2[x])/2}, {x, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]

It is also possible to smooth the average. A linear smoothing filter is a convolution of the data function with a kernel -- below I chose a Gaussian kernel. (I snitched the NConvolve function from [Andrew Moylan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796303).)

```
NConvolve[f_, g_, x_, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f (g /. x -> y - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
g[y_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.1], y];
smooth[x_] = NConvolve[(intL1[y] + intL2[y])/2, g[y], y, x];
Plot[{intL1[x], intL2[x], smooth[x]}, {x, 0.5, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach -- use `TemporalData`:

```
td = TemporalData[{list1, list2}];
{min, max} = {Max@Min@#, Min@Max@#2} & @@ td["Times"];
r1 = Range[min, max, .02];
tdm = TemporalData[Mean[td@r1], {r1}];
ListPlot[Join[td["Paths"], tdm["Paths"]], Joined -> {False, False, True}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Join[td["Paths"], tdm["Path", All, {min, max, (max - min)/20}]], 
         Joined -> {False, False, True}]
```

[image]